# Why doesn't this function make the array null?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider this snippet, why doesn't it set `a` to null if it sets `test`'s `b` property to 2?

```
var test = [];

function clear(a) {
  a.b = 2;
  a = null;
  console.log(a);                         // null
}

clear(test);

console.log(test);                        // [b: 2]
console.log(test.b);                      // 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `test` is a *reference to an* object (array specifically), essentially an arrow pointing to where the array is stored in memory. It's value is its reference to the array in memory.

When you pass it to the function `clear`, `a` now holds a new reference, pointing to the same array in memory, thus modifying the `b` property reflects the change on `test`. Both references see that you've changed the `b` property because they point to the same array.

Then you set `a` to null. `a` and `test` are separate references pointing to the same array, so you break `a`'s connection to the array but not `test`'s. `test` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is b = 2 added to the array

Because you added it to the array before you set `a` to `null`.

> but it does not become null?

You set the `a` variable to `null`. That doesn't touch the `test` variable or the `b` property of the array.